# "Navigation took more than 30000ms. Please increase the navigationTimeout" - working locally but issue in GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, taiko, timeouterror

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Open the browser (chrome) in headless mode

```
await openBrowser({
        headless: headless,
        args: ["--no-sandbox"]
    });
    console.log('Browser opened.');
    gauge.message('Browser opened.');
```

Goto url

```
await goto(url);
```

tried all the below solutions, but none is working -

`goto(url, {waitForEvents:\['firstMeaningfulPaint'\]});`

`goto(url,{timeout:90000, navigationTimeout:90000});`

`goto(url,{timeout:120000, navigationTimeout:90000});`

`goto(url,{waitForEvents:\['loadEventFired'\]});`

`goto(url,{navigationTimeout:90000});`

`goto(url,{navigationTimeout:120000});`

`goto(url,{ waitForStart: 0 });`

`setConfig( { waitForNavigation: false}); # Before goto call`

Script is working locally but issue in GitLab pipeline

**See error**

> Error Message: Error: Navigation took more than 30000ms. Please
> increase the navigationTimeout.

> ```
> Stacktrace: 
> Error: Navigation took more than 30000ms. Please increase the navigationTimeout.
>     at doActionAwaitingNavigation (node_modules/taiko/lib/doActionAwaitingNavigation.js:66:13)
>     at async module.exports.goto (node_modules/taiko/lib/taiko.js:744:3)
>     at async module.exports.<computed> (node_modules/taiko/lib/taiko.js:2620:14)
>     at async Object.<anonymous> (tests/step_implementation.js:36:5)
> ```

or

> Error Message: Error: Timed out

> ```
>     Stacktrace: 
>     Error: Timed out
>         at Timeout.<anonymous> (/root/.gauge/plugins/js/2.4.0/src/test.js:44:23)
>         at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
>         at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
> ```

I tried setting out different timeouts, waitForEvents but none of it worked.

Comment: Do you have a last known good configuration that you can restore?

Comment: what exact configuration you are looking for?

Comment: the last one that was working before any changes were introduced that led to the timeout. but seeing you asking is a strong sign, that you're not aware of a working one.

Comment: Yes exactly.. it never worked in GitLab pipeline. While it is working locally.

Comment: Why not compare the gitlab-runner configuration you use locally with the one you use on the remote system?